# Save data in a SortedDictionary by a resource file (txt)

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a txt file saved in an resource file (*.resx) with some information:

```
    23,TRUNK-1,Trunk-1,,[Barry_Boehm]   
    24,TRUNK-2,Trunk-2,,[Barry_Boehm]   
    25,LEAF-1,Leaf-1,,[Barry_Boehm] 
    26,LEAF-2,Leaf-2,,[Barry_Boehm] 
    136,UDPLite,,,[RFC3828]
```

... and want to save the first and second entry into a SortedDictionary:

```
    23,TRUNK-1  
    24,TRUNK-2  
    25,LEAF-1
    26,LEAF-2
    136,UDPLite
```

---

```
public static SortedDictionary<UInt16, string> xTypes = new SortedDictionary<UInt16, string>();

String[] rows = Regex.Split(Resources.ProTypes.ProTypesSource, "\r\n");

foreach (var i in rows)
{
    String[] words = i.Split(new[] { ',' });

    ...

    xTypes.Add(proNumber, proName);
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `xTypes.Add(UInt16.Parse(words[0]), words[1]);` ?

Comment: I thought there is maybe a better/faster solution. Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static SortedDictionary<UInt16, string> xTypes = new SortedDictionary<UInt16, string>();

String[] rows = Regex.Split(Resources.ProTypes.ProTypesSource, "\r\n");

foreach (var i in rows){
    String[] words = i.Split(new[] { ',' });
    xTypes.Add(UInt16.Parse(words[0]), words[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
        SortedDictionary<UInt16, string> xTypes = new SortedDictionary<UInt16, string>();

        String[] rows = Regex.Split("23,TRUNK-1,Trunk-1,,[Barry_Boehm]", "\r\n");

        foreach (var i in rows)
        {
            String[] words = i.Split(new[] { ',' });

            UInt16 proNumber = Convert.ToUInt16(words[0]);
            string proName = words[1];

            xTypes.Add(proNumber, proName);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have done almost everything:

```
foreach (var i in rows)
{
    String[] words = i.Split(new[] { ',' });

    UInt16 proNumber= UInt16.Parse(words[0]);
    string  proName=words[1];

    xTypes.Add(proNumber, proName);
}
```